# Adding Isolated Storage to Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 Viewmodel

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I'm creating an enhanced note-taking-like app (in the databound app template) where in each individual note, there is a button that launches a file picker where the user can choose images from their picture library. Essentially, I wanted each note to have its own collection of images (though not to be displayed on the page). In the viewmodel of the project, I have an item model for each note (note model) that contains properties for the note ID and the text of the note. Each note has its own ID based on date time ticks. I tried adding another property to the note model so each note will essentially have its own storage folder where files can be saved to and loaded from (in the OnNavigated to and from methods), but I wasn't really sure how to implement this feature. If there happens to be an alternative way to store the images selected in the filepicker to a unique storage space for each note, I am open to any suggestions. I just wanted to be able to allow the user to save a specific set of images to each note and to pass that folder to another method where it can be manipulated. I'm not actually going to display the images in the app itself, which is why I'm not binding the images to a view control. Here is what I tried so far (I'll post all of the item model properties for reference):

```
    private string _id;
    public string ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }



    private string _modDate;

    public string ModifiedDate
    {
        get { return _modDate; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _modDate)
            {
                _modDate = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ModifiedDate");
            }
        }
    }

    IsolatedStorageFile Playlist = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    private IsolatedStorageFile  _playlist;
    public IsolatedStorageFile  Playlist
    {
        get { return _playlist; }
        set
        {

            if (value.ToString() != _id)
            {
                _playlist = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Playlist");
            }
        }
    }


    private string _note;
    public string Note
    {
        get { return _note; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _note = value;
                ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                string[] lines = _note.Split('\n');

                if (lines.Length > 0)
                    FirstLine = lines[0];
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Note");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _firstLine;
    public string FirstLine
    {
        get { return _firstLine; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _firstLine = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstLine");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should put the accessor for an isolated storage into a service, it should not be called directly from the VM. Create a class IsolatedStoageProviderService which inherts from IStorageProviderService, so you can easly use another way to store your data if you want to.

Comment: I'm trying to find some documentation on this class as I'm not familiar with it. I haven't found anything yet. So are you saying that every time a new note is create, that I should use the get method of the IsolatedStoageProviderService class in order to create a new storage space in isolated storage where files chosen in that specific note can be stored? I'm just not exactly sure how to implement this.